# How can I install debuggerWorker.js on React Native debugger?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I am following the Debugging page of the official doc as below URL.
On the "Inspecting Component Instances" it says "Make sure that the dropdown in the top left corner of the Chrome console says debuggerWorker.js. This step is essential." But I can't find debuggerWorker.js on my dev tools.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools

What steps should I take to install debuggerWorker.js?

[image: This is my chrome dev tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in Page panel, not overrides
[image]